# Como arrumar o seguinte erro: Array to string conversion?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando `extrair os dados de quantidade de produtos` de uma tabela mas não estou conseguindo.

Já tentei usar o `Foreach` mas não funcionou.

Também alguma forma de retirar os dados da tabela sem ser pelo formato `array`?

**Código abaixo:**

```
<?php

  require_once 'lib/conn.php';
  $sql = "SELECT SUM(quantidade) AS 'Quantidade de Produtos no Estoque'FROM tbl_estoque";
  $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
  $quantidade_estoque = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  <td><?=$quantidade_estoque?></td>

?>
```

Comment: O que está retornando nesse array? `$quantidade_estoque` poderia postar o resultado do `var_dump($quantidade_estoque);`?

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'Quantidade de Produtos no Estoque' => string '33' (length=2) Essa é a saída do var_dump

Comment: O erro é claro: `Array to string conversion` Você não pode imprimir/visualizar um `array` com um echo, pois ele é usado apenas em uma string; faça o seguinte: `$quantidade_estoque[0]` para pegar a posição 0 o array;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a query só retorna uma coluna, e considerando que você está usando PDO, pode fazer assim:

```
$quantidade_estoque = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou certinho.